# Error in s$CoefTable : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors for export_sums command in R

Tags: vector, atomic

I am exporting summary result tables for mlogit. After running the regression, I have following codes to export results to docx file.

> 

````
library(huxtable)
library(officer)
library(flextable)
export_summs(cl, mxl1.data, mxl2.data, mxl3.data, scale = TRUE, number_format= "%.4g", to.file = "docx", file.name = "file.docx")```

However, I got the error "Error in s$CoefTable : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Really look forward to your help. Thank you
````